# UITapGestureRecognizer not working when added for UIView Cannot detect the issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

`UITapGestureRecognizer` not working when added for `UIView`. Cannot detect the issue.

Note: I am not using it in `ViewDidLoad`. Please help me is solving the problem. Thanks in Advance.

```
-(void)setSegmentValues:(NSArray *) values 
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
    tap1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tap1.delegate=self;
    [val1 addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
    val1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 200, 70, 40)];
    val1.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
    label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,70, 40)];
    label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    label1.text = [values objectAtIndex:0];
    label1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    val1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [val1 addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
    [val1 addSubview:label1];
    [self addSubview:val1];
}
```

Other stuffs:

```
- (void)tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"success1");
} 

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Note: I've also added `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

Comment: **This is my final code and it works**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do like this.. You will get correct solution..

```
-(void)setSegmentValues:(NSArray *)values bgColor:(UIColor *)color
    {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectedIndexValue:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

        viewOne = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 50, 80, 60)];
        viewOne.backgroundColor = color;
        viewOne.tag = 0;
        UILabel *lblOne = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 60)];
        lblOne.text = [values objectAtIndex:0];
        lblOne.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lblOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [viewOne addSubview:lblOne];

        viewOne.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [viewOne addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [self addSubview:viewOne];
    }

-(void)selectedIndexValue:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    int myViewTag = gesture.view.tag; 
    if (myViewTag == 0) 
    {
        selectedIndex1 = 0;
        self.lblValue.text = [valueArray objectAtIndex:myViewTag];
        viewOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:57.0f green:122.0f blue:255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        viewTwo.backgroundColor = viewColor;
        viewThree.backgroundColor = viewColor;
    }
[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

Comment: I undeleted for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Is you control even going in "setSegmentValues:" method? 
Make sure your method is being called from viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear or any IBAction.

Comment: Ya, my control is going in setSegmentValues method. should not i use like this ? without calling from viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear ?

Comment: you can use like this, but you need to call it from somewhere sothat method can get executed. viewDidLoad & viewWillAppear & viewDidAppear are lifecycle methods, so they get executed by themselves.
You can call your method from them or from any IBAction, like a button click.

Comment: just add this in viewDidLoad and try:
[self setSegmentValues:abcArray];

Answer (score 1):

this is error:

```
[val1 addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
val1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 200, 70, 40)];
```

write:

```
val1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 200, 70, 40)];
[val1 addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
```

Comment: May be that is also an error i made. But still the issue is there.It dosnt works. Thank you for your Response

Comment: yeah it was a mistake thanks . But this doesn't solve the issue Gesture doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

You added a gesture to an UiView without alloc init.
Initialize the View before adding Gesture to it

Please use this code

```
-(void)setSegmentValues:(NSArray *) values 
 {
  val1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 200, 70, 40)];
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self      action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
  tap1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
  tap1.delegate=self;
  [val1 addGestureRecognizer:tap1];

  val1.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
  label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,70, 40)];
   label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
  label1.text = [values objectAtIndex:0];
  label1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
  val1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
  [val1 addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
  [val1 addSubview:label1];
   [self addSubview:val1]
 }
```

Comment: try disabling userInteration for label